# If $P(\max_{n \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq m} \min \{|S_i - S_j|, |S_k - S_j|\} \geq \lambda)$ is bounded appropriately, does $\sum \xi_j$ converge a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Suppose that

$$E\left[|S_j - S_i|^\gamma |S_k - S_j|^\gamma \right] \leq \left(\sum_{i < l \leq j} u_l\right)^\alpha \left(\sum_{j < l \leq k} u_l\right)^\alpha$$

for $0 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq m$ with $S_k = \sum_{i \leq k} \xi_i$ ($S_0 = 0$) and $\gamma, \alpha$ postitive, and $u_l \geq 0$ for every $l$.

It follows from a theorem in Billingsley's book *Convergence of Probability Measures* (first edition) that

$$P\left(\max_{n \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq m} \min \{|S_i - S_j|, |S_k - S_j|\} \geq \lambda\right) \leq \frac{K}{\lambda^{2\gamma}} \left(u_{n+1} + \ldots + u_{m}\right)^{2\alpha} \times \min_{n + 1 \leq h \leq m}\left(1 - \frac{u_h}{u_{n + 1} + \ldots + u_m}\right)$$

where $K$ depends only on $\lambda$ and $\gamma$.

Assume additionally that $\sum u_l < \infty$. Can we use the above bounded probability to show that $\sum \xi_i < \infty$ almost surely?

---

I think we can simplify things by saying that since $\min_{n + 1 \leq h \leq m}\left(1 - \frac{u_h}{u_{n + 1} + \ldots + u_m}\right) \leq 1$ we actually only need to work with

$$P\left(\max_{n \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq m} \min \{|S_i - S_j|, |S_k - S_j|\} \geq \lambda\right) \leq \frac{K}{\lambda^{2\gamma}} \left(u_{n+1} + \ldots + u_{m}\right)^{2\alpha}$$

This question is related to a [question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064734/if-e-sum-i-l-leq-j-xi-l-gamma-leq-sum-i-l-leq-j-u-l-alpha) and I think a similar approach to the solution given there could be used here, but I don't know how to do it. I want to relate $\max_{n \leq i, j \leq m} |S_i - S_j|$ to $\max_{n \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq m} \min \{|S_i - S_j|, |S_k - S_j|\}$ but I don't know if I can do so in a useful way.

Comment: Bump because bounty is about to expire tomorrow. Even an incomplete answer with a great idea could be rewarded.

Comment: Even a comment such as this cannot be done. This is one of Billingsley's problems, but he left it pretty open ended.